# SKShapeNode with UIBezierPath is not filled entirely

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

I want to draw a filled sector of a circle using SKShapeNode with UIBezierPath.
I works well in most cases, but with smaller angles the shape is not filled entirely(right under the arc there is a little gap). Like this:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(500, 300) ;

UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath addArcWithCenter:center radius:400   startAngle:1.825777 endAngle:2.011118 clockwise:YES];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:center];
[bezierPath closePath];

SKShapeNode *shapeNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:bezierPath.CGPath];
shapeNode.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
shapeNode.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self addChild:shapeNode];
```

The result is the same on iPad and on the simulator (iOS 8.1).

Am I doing something wrong or it is some limitation or bug?

If it's not possible to draw this shape more accurately with these API, could you please suggest some other ways to draw it in the context of SpriteKit game.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a SKShapeNode bug, see http://sartak.org/2014/03/skshapenode-you-are-dead-to-me.html

One fix, would be to increase the lineWidth of the SKShapeNode so it fills up the gap.

`shapeNode.lineWidth = 4`

You could instead do the same with UIKit using the same bezierPath and fill and stroke it in drawRect.

Comment: I need this shape to become a SpriteKit node, not simply draw it. I don't understand how I can achive it using drawRect. Could you please describe it in more details.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I believe I ecountered this problem with lineWidth > 4

Comment: @akmidd for drawRect sorry you won't be able to use it in a SpriteKit node, the idea was to drop SpriteKit and do all your animation/drawing in UIKit.

Comment: I have tried to draw my shapes with Core Graphics into a UIImage and then using it as a texture for SKSpriteNode. This way shapes are rendered perfectly, but performace degraded noticeably when there are multiple nodes to be generated in real time. So for now I rolled back to using  SKShapeNode but excluded arcs from my shapes. I gues, for not performance critical tasks aproach CoreGraphics > UIImage > SKSpriteNode could work.